# Jquery mobile custom menu with images

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Hello I'm trying to build a custom menu with images in jquery mobile. It's working but if I click on the button to swith the entry the images are not showing up only the text is showing.

I use this on html side:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="german" class="german">German</option>
        <option value="belgium" class="belgium">Belgium</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and this on css side:

```
.german {background: url(../images/flags/german.gif) 5px 50% no-repeat; padding: 5px 0 5px 55px; font-size: 16px;}
.belgium {background: url(../images/flags/belgium.gif) 5px 50% no-repeat; padding: 5px 0 5px 55px; font-size: 16px;}
```

but like I said it does not show me background images while switching the entry. Like here:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add `data-native-menu="false"` to a `select`, jQM converts it into either a *popup* or a *dialog* based on number of `option` as well as viewport's height.

The *popup* or *dialog* receives an `id` of the `select` but with an extra `listbox`. So the new `id` is `select-custom-1-listbox`. The *options* are converted into *listview* `li` elements

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">German</a>
</li>
```

**Solution - CSS:**

```
#select-custom-1-listbox li:nth-child(1) a {
  background: url(german.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 55px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#select-custom-1-listbox li:nth-child(2) a {
  background: url(belgium.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 55px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b64yp/)**

---

**Solution - JS**

Add classes to `li`'s buttons on `popupbeforeposition`. This event fires before *popup* is visible. At that stage, add classes to both buttons but *once* only "`.one()`".

```
$(document).one("popupbeforeposition", "#select-custom-1-listbox", function () {
    $("li a:eq(0)", this).addClass("german");
    $("li a:eq(1)", this).addClass("belgium");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hf7YP/)**

Comment: @Kingalione you're welcome akhi ;) answer is updated.

Comment: If I use no text in the option tag the selector is not working well. What I try to do is to show the language text only in switching mode. If a entry is selected the text should not show so only the flag is visible. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Kingalione I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Omar I'm still waiting for a answer of you :)

Comment: @king sorry, totally forgot about it.